# Scrolling RecyclerView freezes on long TextViews

Tags: android, textview, android-recyclerview, charsequence

I am trying to implement a comment section-style layout using a `RecyclerView`. I have a list of `CharSequence` objects (each the result of `Html.fromHtml(String, null, null)`) which I use to populate this `RecyclerView`.

Here is the `RecyclerView` layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Here is the `TextView` layout:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.4"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:textSize="15sp"/>
```

Here is the `ViewHolder`:

```java
public final class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    @Bind(R.id.text) TextView text; // ButterKnife

    public ItemHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        text.setMovementMethod(new LinkMovementMethod());
    }

    public void bind(CharSequence cs) {
        text.setText(cs);
    }
```

The rest is pretty standard. The `RecyclerView` is given a `LinearLayoutManager` and an `Adapter` that reads from the list and creates `ViewHolder` instances. I did not call `setHasFixedSize(true)` because I want to be able to swap the contents of the adapter and the number of items might not always be the same.

The setup works for most input, but the problem is that some of the `CharSequence`s are over 100 lines long, and when scrolling, the `RecyclerView` pauses for about half a second just before it reaches them and then continues scrolling. It doesn't just happen once either. When I scroll back up to the item, it freezes again, and then everytime I scroll the item out of view and scroll back down to it, the view freezes again. How do I fix this?

Comment: what does your `onBindViewHolder` look like?

Comment: It is never advisable to use recyclerview for such a purpose. Since your String (CharSequence) text is very large, it takes a few microseconds (or seconds) to render completely and that happens with all the instance views in the visible region (not yet recycled). A quick solution could be offloading the setText part to a different background thread, freeing the UI thread to create instances freely. Also don't put a lot of content directly to the UI thread.

Comment: @NileshSingh How to offloading settext of background thread, holder doexnot allow to change any data except ui thread, please provide some example or reference to do that.