# Recycler view onBindViewHolder freezes with setText on textView with reallylarge text

Tags: android, performance, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

adapter onBindViewHolder method:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int i) {
    if (holder  instanceof TextFeedHolder) {
        ((TextFeedHolder) holder).bind_view(module.feeds.get(i));
```

holder bind_view method:

```
public void bind_view(final Feed feed) {
    message.setText(feed.body.message);
```

**feed.body.message** is a string of length around 20000 character.

when **onBindViewHolder** method gets called for **TextFeedHolder** recycler view gets freeze for 10-20 milliseconds while scrolling which is visible to eyes, how to solve this?

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to append all 20,000 characters to the TextView? Why not just set the text to use a small portion of the string with an option to expand/view the rest with a click?

Comment: @jburn2712 in this textviewholder i need to display all text at once with no actions like seemore.

Comment: I'm not really sure what to tell you then. There's no faster way to set all the text at once than calling `setText()`

Comment: @jburn2712 any idea on 2nd comment of this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40025436/scrolling-recyclerview-freezes-on-long-textviews

Comment: Like @jburn2712 said, you need to decide: Either display all of it and live with the delay or displays some of the text and allow the user to click to view the whole thing.

Comment: @Aman Jain setting text into a text view can't be done from a background thread. Any interaction with Views that were initialized on the main thread must be done on the main thread. A surface view renders views on a background thread so maybe you could try using that but I don't have any experience with surface views and I don't know if it would work